# Inserting data from controller to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I try to create a graph using Chart.js and get the data from database, but I am confused how to pass the data to an array variable in view.

This is the Controller

```
public function ApiLaporanBulanan()
{
    $data = DB::table("transaksipenjualan")->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggaltransaksi) AS Bulan, SUM(total) as Pendapatan'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggaltransaksi)'))
    ->get();
    return response()->json($data);

    //Accessing Data
    dd($data[0]->Bulan);
}
```

This is the script in view

```
<script>
  var url = "{{url('laporan/pendapatanAPI')}}";
  var Bulan = [];
  var Pendapatan = [];
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get(url, function(response){
      response.forEach(function(data){
          Bulan.push(data->Bulan);
          Pendapatan.push(data->Pendapatan);
      });
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: Bulan,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Nilai Pendapatan',
                    data: Pendapatan,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can i know your blade page name??

Comment: I worked with chat,js in blades by formating data in the controller and then passing it to javsacript array itself. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Route::get('laporan/pendapatanAPI', 'ReportController@ApiLaporanBulanan');

Comment: if you are familiar with using packages  https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts

Comment: i mean your view blade file where you want to show blade the chart js

Comment: @Boni pendapatanBulanan.blade.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two array in your controller.

```
$label = [];
$dataset = [];
```

and loop through your collection and push data to these arrays

```
foreach($data as $value){
   $label[] = $value->data_field;
   $dataset[] = $value->data_field;
}
```

And pass it to your blade and assign these array to your chart

```
...
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: Bulan,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Nilai Pendapatan',// label data
                    data: Pendapatan, // dataset
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
....
```

Comment: Is this the right way to pass the data?
`return response()->json(array('Bulan'=>$label, 'Pendapatan'=>$data));`